# Divs HTML + CSS ajuste

Tags: html

Boas, a minha duvida é na minha página tenho o menu e o rodapé 100% funcional mas não consigo adaptar a div do "corpo" ou "content" queria conforme o conteudo que fosse colocado ela aumenta-se, o meu problema quando tento fazer isso a informação "passa" o rodapé e continua e eu não queria isso, alguem sabe como ajudar?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclua o código que tens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não estou entendendo muito bem a sua pergunta, coloca seu código aqui pra eu dar uma olhada, mas de antemão suponho q esteja usando um valor fixo no <kbd>height</kbd>, remova esse valor fixo e a div deve crescer junto com seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Basta deixar a div do corpo sem definir a altura, e ela vai se ajustar automaticamente.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#geral{
  width: 700px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: auto;
}
#cabecalho{
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
#conteudo{
  width: 660px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
#rodape{
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="geral">
  <div id="cabecalho">
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo">
    orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris venenatis sem ut ultricies ornare. Aliquam cursus, mi id porta volutpat, massa nibh tincidunt mi, sed lobortis orci urna vel turpis. Mauris ultricies leo in elementum commodo. Mauris enim orci, congue in urna quis, suscipit semper nunc. Phasellus iaculis, erat non finibus aliquet, eros tellus cursus enim, ut ullamcorper urna sapien sed ante. Mauris vitae leo in libero pharetra ornare. Nunc eleifend mi a elementum blandit. Proin massa lacus, pretium sit amet venenatis vitae, pellentesque nec velit. Sed sagittis quis ante a efficitur. Sed laoreet neque dictum purus mollis tempus.

Phasellus rutrum dui eget convallis varius. Fusce massa dui, rhoncus eu massa nec, scelerisque rutrum lorem. Donec eu pellentesque magna. Donec dapibus rhoncus felis. Nam auctor sapien felis, quis faucibus nisi pharetra eu. Duis vel velit nibh. Vivamus varius, risus quis ultrices commodo, urna nisl luctus eros, eget facilisis lectus massa a nisl. Maecenas in volutpat sapien, in consequat est. Pellentesque quis facilisis odio, ac tincidunt libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut ultricies mollis nibh id ullamcorper.

Nulla vitae malesuada leo. Aenean ultrices commodo congue. Aenean a ligula mi. Sed fermentum a dui ac bibendum. Proin non fermentum ante. Maecenas posuere eget metus non luctus. Duis viverra risus consequat, dignissim sem at, pharetra nibh. Phasellus vehicula erat sed venenatis porttitor. Curabitur vitae purus ac felis mattis rutrum. Donec neque libero, sodales eu urna at, auctor elementum justo. Quisque sit amet nisl sodales, tempor nibh sit amet, maximus diam. Aliquam et justo tincidunt, pulvinar eros sit amet, vehicula enim. Vestibulum ornare, purus sed convallis dignissim, nunc sapien facilisis ipsum, in faucibus tellus lectus eget nibh. In venenatis pellentesque auctor. 
  </div>
  <div id="rodape">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pelo CSS assim estas a limitar um pouco o width e o height não? eu coloquei por percentagem,  ou não tem influencia pela div do conteudo?

Comment: Já consegui, obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha conseguido. Quando você define medidas em porcentagem, essa porcentagem é tomada com base na medida do elemento pai. Por exemplo: uma `div` com largura de `50%` dentro de outra `div` de `300px` terá uma largura de `150px`.